# Efficiency of FIR filter in verilog language

Tags: verilog, digital-communications, demodulation, digital-filter, fir

Implementing a 4-tap FIR unity coefficients, is this code efficient in power and area ?

```
always@(posedge Clk)
begin
  //unit delays using flip flops
  xn0<=Xin; //x[n]
  xn1<=xn0; //x[n-1]
  xn2<=xn1; //x[n-2]
  xn3<=xn2; //x[n-3]
  add0<=xn0+xn1;
  add1<=xn2+xn3;
  add_all<=add01+add23
  Yout<=add_all;
end//aways
```

Comment: Are you okay with only getting the output 4 cycles after the inputs? What I mean is this filter is giving \$y[n] = x[n-4] + x[n-5] + x[n-6] + x[n-7]\$ (if I calculated correctly). Is that the filter you want? Because often we want the output to depend on the most recent inputs available. But other times a delay may be acceptable to save power or area.

Comment: No I want x[n]+x[n-1]+x[n-2]+x[n-3]

Answer (score 1):

You are creating additional pipeline steps for the intermediates. This introduces an additional delay, as The Photon suggested in the comments, and the output is \$x[n-7] + x[n-6] + x[n-5] + x[n-4]\$.

The additional pipeline steps can give you a higher \$f_{max}\$, but that is probably not what you want.

The minimum delay variant \$x[n-3] + x[n-2] + x[n-1] + x[n]\$ is more complex, because it would end in a combinatorial stage, and adding more combinatorial outputs would reduce \$f_{max}\$. That stage would have

```
assign Yout = Xin + xn1 + xn2 + xn3;
```

to calculate the output, and

```
always @ (posedge Clk)
begin
    xn1 <= Xin;
    xn2 <= xn1;
    xn3 <= xn2;
end
```

You see that there is no register stage for `xn0` here, because that is part of the component feeding `Xin`, which is expected to be synchronous to `Clk` as well.

A one-clock delay compromise would be

```
assign Yout = xn0 + xn1 + xn2 + xn3;

always @ (posedge Clk)
begin
    xn0 <= Xin;
    xn1 <= xn0;
    xn2 <= xn1;
    xn3 <= xn2;
end
```

This reduces routing complexity at the cost of one cycle delay. Whether that is a good trade-off is an engineering decision.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in following

```
   assign add01   = xn0+xn1;
   assign add23   = xn2+xn3;
   assign add_all = add01+add23;
   assign Yout    = add_all;

   always @ (posedge Clk or negedge reset_n)
   begin
     if(~reset_n)
     begin
       xn0  <= 'd0  
       xn1  <= 'd0
      xn2  <= 'd0
   xn3  <= 'd0
   Yout <= 'd0
 end
 else
 begin
 //unit delays using flip flops
   xn0    <=Xin; //x[n]
   xn1    <=xn0; //x[n-1]
   xn2    <=xn1; //x[n-2]
   xn3    <=xn2; //x[n-3]
 end
end //always
```